# How to restore deleted services to an aws ECS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-service-catalog

I have accidentally deleted an AWS ECS cluster, because of which all the running services in side it are been terminated. Is there any way to restore them all?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restore deleted cluster. But you are still having all the task-definitions so you can recreate services using them.